# Limiting pub/sub messages

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a service which uses google cloud pub/sub to handle a job requests, but when there is a large number of requests, it causes the docker pod to fail. how can i limit the rate of messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should subscribe with flow control as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-subscriber-flow-settings#pubsub_subscriber_flow_settings-nodejs)

Comment: with that said, it might still be a good idea to see maybe there is room to improve your service and check if would also help preventing the pod to get shut down